# Why I get Windows namespace is reserved error after I added Windows.winmd?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, windows-8.1-universal

This is an issue I faced when I tried to use encryption safe Random generating method for my Windows8.1 app (Both WindowsPhone and WinRT). However after adding "Windows.winmd" to my portable project(an Utility project). I can compile the portable project while my WinRT project cannot compile because of 4000+ errors like this [image] Any idea? Here is the reference I use for the portable project[image]

Here is the namespaces I used 
[image]

And here is the reference I used for the WinUWP project (UWP, WinRT, WindowsPhone project are essentially doing the same thing, UWP is in a different solution, but has the same issue)
[image]

Could anyone explain why add Windows.winmd to portable project will lead to error in WinRT|WinPhone|UWP project inside the same solution? After all I didn't add it to the WinRT|WinPhone|UWP project.

Comment: the error is telling you what the issue is .. can you not rename the namespace to something else ? or `Alias the namespace` google it if you are not familiar with how to Alias a namespace..

Comment: @MethodMan Isn't Windows.winmd system metadata? I cannot change it, I just add it from system directory

Comment: you are not changing their assembly however when you reference the assembly in your code you can alias it.. perhaps you should add in the code from both namespaces you're using so I can see exactly what it is you're doing.. since I can't see what it is you're doing on your end.. thanks

Comment: @MethodMan I updated the question, thank you for taking your time into this.

Comment: @MethodMan I have this issue while trying to figure out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41047566/how-to-generate-random-number-in-windows-8-1-portable-project-not-using-cryptogr

Comment: just like I said earlier you could still alias the namespace that's in conflict

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130241/discussion-between-litaoshen-and-methodman).

Comment: @MethodMan This is the chat provided by StackOverflow, thanks!